# Dataflow Streaming Job - Error writing to BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Running into error writing to BigQuery through Apache Beam Dataflow job using 'FILE_LOADS' technique. The Streaming INSERT (else block) works fine and as expected. The 'FILE_LOAD' (if block) fails with error given below after the code. The temporary files on the GCS the bucket is valid JSON objects.

Sample raw events from Pub/Sub:

```
"{'event': 'test', 'entityId': 13615316690, 'eventTime': '2020-08-12T15:56:07.130899+00:00', 'targetEntityId': 8947793, 'targetEntityType': 'item', 'entityType': 'guest', 'properties': {}}" 
 
"{'event': 'test', 'entityId': 13615316690, 'eventTime': '2020-08-12T15:56:07.130899+00:00', 'targetEntityId': 8947793, 'targetEntityType': 'item', 'entityType': 'guest', 'properties': {‘action’: ‘delete’}}"
```

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import logging
import sys
import traceback
import argparse
import ast
import json
import datetime
import dateutil.parser as date_parser

import apache_beam as beam
import apache_beam.pvalue as pvalue
from google.cloud.bigquery import CreateDisposition, WriteDisposition
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools import RetryStrategy

def get_values(element):
    # convert properties from dict to arr of dicts to form a repeatable bq table record
    prop_list = [{'property_name': k, 'property_value': v} for k, v in element['properties'].items()]
    date_parsed = date_parser.parse(element.get('eventTime'))
    event_time = date_parsed.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00')
    
    raw_value = {'event': element.get('event'),
                 'entity_type': element.get('entityType'),
                 'entity_id': element.get('entityId'),
                 'target_entity_type': element.get('targetEntityType'),
                 'target_entity_id': element.get('targetEntityId'),
                 'event_time': event_time,
                 'properties': prop_list
                 }

    return raw_value

def stream_to_bq(c: dict):
    argv = [
        f'--project={c["PROJECT"]}',
        f'--runner=DataflowRunner',
        f'--job_name={c["JOBNAME"]}',
        f'--save_main_session',
        f'--staging_location=gs://{c["BUCKET_NAME"]}/{c["STAGING_LOCATION"]}',
        f'--temp_location=gs://{c["BUCKET_NAME"]}/{c["TEMP_LOCATION"]}',
        f'--network={c["NETWORKPATH"]}',
        f'--subnetwork={c["SUBNETWORKPATH"]}',
        f'--region={c["REGION"]}',
        f'--service_account_email={c["SERVICE_ACCOUNT"]}',
        # f'--setup_file=./setup.py',
        # f'--autoscaling_algorithm=THROUGHPUT_BASED',
        # f'--maxWorkers=15',
        # f'--experiments=shuffle_mode=service',
        '--no_use_public_ips',
        f'--streaming'
    ]

    if c['FILE_LOAD']:
        argv.append('--experiments=allow_non_updatable_job')
        argv.append('--experiments=use_beam_bq_sink')

    p = beam.Pipeline(argv=argv)
    valid_msgs = (p
                          | 'Read from Pubsub' >>
                          beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=c['SUBSCRIPTION']).with_output_types(bytes)
                          )

    records = (valid_msgs
               | 'Event Parser(BQ Row) ' >> beam.Map(get_values)
               )

    # Load data to BigQuery using - 'Load Jobs' or 'Streaming Insert', choice based on latency expectation.
    if c['FILE_LOAD']:
        records | 'Write Result to BQ' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(c["RAW_TABLE"],
                                                                  project=c["PROJECT"],
                                                                  dataset=c["DATASET_NAME"],
                                                                  method='FILE_LOADS',
                                                                  triggering_frequency=c['FILE_LOAD_FREQUENCY'],
                                                                  create_disposition=CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
                                                                  write_disposition=WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
                                                                  )

        
    else:
        records | 'Write Result to BQ' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(c["RAW_TABLE"],
                                                                  project=c["PROJECT"],
                                                                  dataset=c["DATASET_NAME"],
                                                                  create_disposition=CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
                                                                  write_disposition=WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                                                  insert_retry_strategy=RetryStrategy.RETRY_ON_TRANSIENT_ERROR
                                                                  )

    

    p.run()
```

Error from the Dataflow job:

```
message: 'Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.' reason: 'invalid'> [while running 'generatedPtransform-1801'] java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357) java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895) org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MoreFutures.get(MoreFutures.java:57)
```

Comment: How did it go? Were you able to find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks as a wrong load to BigQuery. My recommendation is to try to make a test load job outside Dataflow, to be sure that your schema and data structure is fine. You can follow [this BQ documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#bq).

Also, I noticed that you are not specifying the `schema` nor `SCHEMA_AUTODETECT`. I suggest you do specify it.

To understand the errors, try to inspect the Dataflow Jobs logs, the probably contain a lot of info. If you have Load jobs failing, you can inspect those in BigQuery, they will also get you more info about what's failing. You can use this StackDriver log to find the BQ load job IDs:

```
resource.type="dataflow_step"
resource.labels.job_id= < YOUR DF JOB ID >
jsonPayload.message:("Triggering job" OR "beam_load")
```

I'm quite convince the issue is happening either by an issue with the repeated field `properties` or with the schema, considering it only fails with Load Job, schema seems more likely (maybe the schema for that table is wrong). Any how, here you have a working pipeline, I tested it on my side and both BQ inserts worked:

```
        schema = {
            "fields":
                [
                    {
                        "name": "name",
                        "type": "STRING"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "repeated",
                        "type": "RECORD",
                        "mode": "REPEATED",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "name": "spent",
                                "type": "INTEGER"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "ts",
                                "type": "TIMESTAMP"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }

        def fake_parsing(element):
            # Using a fake parse so it's easier to reproduce
            properties = []

            rnd = random.random()
            if rnd < 0.25:
                dict_prop = {"spent": random.randint(0, 100),
                             "ts": datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00')}
                properties.append(dict_prop)
            elif rnd > 0.75:
                # repeated
                dict_prop = {"spent": random.randint(0, 100),
                             "ts": datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00')}
                properties += [dict_prop, dict_prop]
            elif 0.5 > rnd > 0.75:
                properties.append({"ts": datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00')})

            return {"name": 'inigo',
                    "repeated": properties}

        pubsub = (p | "Read Topic" >> ReadFromPubSub(topic=known_args.topic)
                    | "To Dict" >> beam.Map(fake_parsing))

        pubsub | "Stream To BQ" >> WriteToBigQuery(
            table=f"{known_args.table}_streaming_insert",
            schema=schema,
            write_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
            method="STREAMING_INSERTS")

        pubsub | "Load To BQ" >> WriteToBigQuery(
            table=f"{known_args.table}_load_job",
            schema=schema,
            write_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
            method=WriteToBigQuery.Method.FILE_LOADS,
            triggering_frequency=known_args.triggering,
            insert_retry_strategy="RETRY_ON_TRANSIENT_ERROR")
```

I would recommend you to try parts of the pipeline instead of everything at once, i.e., try first just Load Jobs and, if they fail, inspect why they are failing (in Dataflow logs, BigQuery logs or BigQuery UI). Once that's done, add the Streaming inserts (or the other way around).

Comment: Thank you Inigo, will try it today and keep you posted. Appreciate your prompt response.